# А как у нас относятся к комментариям с вопросами о времени?

Tags: обсуждение

На основе [вопроса](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316726/4928642) на metaSO.

В комментариях к вопросу начинается обсуждение и уточнение деталей. В какой-то момент спрашивающий пишет комментарий с вопросом, собирается ли общающийся с ним ответить за некоторое время, например, два дня.

Допустим ли такой вопрос? Следует ли на него ответить просто да/нет или требуется развёрнутый комментарий, почему этот сайт не предназначен для решения задач за ограниченное время?

Comment: На мой взгляд, требование решить проблему за ограниченное время невежливо по отношению к отвечающим. Я в таких ситуациях молча закрываю вкладку навсегда.

Comment: @VladD, требование "Сделай за 2 дня, мне срочно надо" - да, невежливо. А если вопрос "Вы сможете мне помочь в ближайшее два дня?" - думаю, вполне нормально в плане вежливости.

Comment: Это немного лучше, но по сути то же самое. Я _не знаю_ будет ли у меня время, и не хочу обещать. Своим вопросом автор неявно говорит, что его вопрос чем-то важнее других вопросов. Это может быть и так с его точки зрения, но это его проблема, убедить меня в этом.

Comment: @VladD, но ведь можно ответить и "нет". Разве сам вопрос об этом является проблемой?

Comment: Ну, да, является. Он показывает отношение человека. В качестве далёкой аналогии, если при знакомстве с девушкой я сразу же спрошу «у тебя будет время переспать со мной сегодня или завтра», то есть шанс, что она обидится, хотя я ж только спросил.

Comment: Не вижу проблем (не с девушками, конечно же) с такими вопросами в  комментариях. Если кто-то обидится и перестанет отвечать, что ж, ТС-у просто не повезло.

Comment: Это, конечно, пересыпание песка в песочнице, но мне кажется, что VladD в чем-то прав, ведь сложно сказать наверняка будет ли у вас время в ближайшие n дней (ведь ваши планы могут сильно поменяться, а этот сайт, будем честными, лишь волонтерское хобби для большинства пользователей), но с другой стороны, иногда может быть полезным повесить на вопрос ограничитель времени, который бы сообщал отвечающим, что по его окончанию ответ будет не актуален (ну или просто перестанет быть востребованым в каком-либо виде).

Comment: Процитирую [комментарий из обсуждения на англомете](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316726/#comment306845_316726): _Я заметил тенденцию: если кто-то спрашивает подобное в вопросе или комментарии, скорее всего он ответит грубостью, если вы скажете «нет», как бы вежливо вы не говорили. Я не ратую за невежливость, просто не удивляйтесь, если ваша вежливость окажется *односторонней*_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я считаю, что в таком вопросе или даже в вежливой просьбе ничего страшного нет. Надо просто ответить да или нет.

Активность в комментариях даёт спрашивающему понять, что ты можешь ответить. Аналогичные мысли возникают и у других читающих вопрос. В случае, если читатели воспринимают переписку как твою готовность помочь и ответить, они могут начать откладывать или игнорировать этот вопрос.

Прямой вопрос о сроках и отрицательный ответ на него дают читающим понять, что вопрос "свободен". Поэтому такие вопросы допустимы и несут полезную информацию.

Соответственно, на них надо просто отвечать да или нет, не расписывая, почему этот сайт не подходит для срочных задач. Это поможет сориентироваться другим отвечающим. Также не стоит голосовать за закрытие или минусовать вопрос.

> Я могу легко ответить да или нет, но в таком случае он продолжит задавать подобные вопросы. Я не думаю, что люди начинают пропускать вопросы из-за того, что я уточняю детали. Или я ошибаюсь?

Это зависит от множества факторов.

Если я воспринимаю комментарии как подготовку к ответу и я понимаю, что ответ или понимание вопроса требует от меня времени, весьма вероятно, что я подожду некоторое время. Возможно, я добавлю вопрос в избранное, чтобы посмотреть позже, возможно, просто оставлю открытой вкладку браузера, а может даже просто закрою её и забуду об этом вопросе. Вполне возможно что, в случае отсутствия комментариев, я бы сразу начал на него отвечать, но если я вижу что кто-то готовится ответить, я не стану этого делать, если только не увижу в вопросе чего-то весьма интересного для меня. Естественно, речь идёт о нетривиальных вопросах.

Таким образом, уточняющие комментарии могут снижать вероятность ответа от других пользователей, а вопрос о времени ответа просто сбрасывает этот эффект - вопрос снова становится свободным.

> Кажется, имеет место недопонимание назначения Сети. Это не хелпдеск, а собрание знаний. Любые вопросы о времени неприемлемы по определению.

Это цель сети, но не людей. Я говорю не только о спрашивающих, но и об отвечающих. Почему они отвечают? Они просто хотят добавить новый шмоток информации? Или всё же чего-то другого? В [большинстве ответов](/q/305/178988) они говорят об общении, изучении и обучении, помощи другим и т. д. "Я опобликую это и на один огрызок информации станет больше" - ну вот не думают так люди, это не их цель.

Comment: [На английском](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316731/4928642)

Comment: Что значит "вопрос свободен"? Если под вопросом кем-то написано "да, смогу ответить", но я знаю правильный ответ - мне пройти мимо потому что "вопрос кем-то занят"?